# Recurring system crash while using GDAL Georeferencer in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, gdal, georeferencing

I am currently working on aerial images I have to reference in QGIS. I usually use the GDAL tool for that, but during the last days, QGIS crashes all few minutes whenever I use it. I ran into this problem before, but usually a restart of the computer fixed it for some reason. This time, that did not help.

Does anyone know this error and how to avoid it? This problem really gets onto my nerves.

I am using QGIS 2.18.17 on a 64 bit Windows 7 PC.

Comment: This problem may be related to [the bug report #14283](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/14283). Please try the solution in [note-16](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/14283#note-16).

Comment: I tried the solution described in note 16. It did not work and I don't see how it could. The error seems to be related to some kind of memory mismanagment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several older Versions of QGIS I found, that the GDAL Georeferencer Plugin works without the bug described above in Version 2.2.0 Valmiera.

It would be interesting to get some comments, if this version works for other people as well, or just on my system.

Comment: Why don't you use a more recent version instead of going backward?

Comment: The post is more than two years old. The bug was only relevant for 2.18. I did not run into this bug since Version 3 but I have not tried it as excessivly. But it seems to be solved.

Comment: I have no clue as to why this has resurfaced on the main page on the stack exchange as I was browsing questions...